# Finding all other Objects with same Joined Attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I have a Product table, and then ProductsTypes and ProductsOptions tables (join tables for other tables).

Given a Product, I want to find all other products where the Product's Options (i.e., where ProductOptions.product_id == product.id) and ProductTypes are the same.

The best we can come up with is to get all ProductType and ProductOptions, then for each do a join on the table to find where id == id; but this seems inelegant and we feel there should be a way to do this a bit more cleanly.

How would you find other Products where all the joined options and types match the original product?

Using Rails 3.x/Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: You should be able to do: `Product.joins(:products_options)`. I recommend you review http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: can you post your models so we can see your associations?

Comment: Unfortunately no, company code. @fmendez this is not an issue of unfamiliarity with ActiveRecord, ProductOptions is the join table for Options -- I'm trying to find other Products that have the same Product.options; trouble is that there are multiple and where statements filter for attributes on a row; we are looking for where a Product has similar *relationships*, not attributes.